# How to specify the output channel (left,right) with pydub?

Tags: python, audio, channel, pydub

I would like to see the same function found on pygame, channel.set_volume for pygame.mixer.sound. Example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(name_of_the_file)
channel = sound.play()
channel.set_volume(1,1)     #That's what I need...
```

I need it for a program that run o single computer and send information trough a speaker for each work office. Is there something similar on pydub?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the dev version of Pydub (on [github](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/)) you can use the new [`apply_stereo_gain`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentapply_gain_stereo) or [`pan`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentpan) method:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/to/sound.mp3", format="mp3")

# pan 10% left
panned1 = sound.pan(-0.1)

# left channel lowered 6 dB, right channel unchanged
panned2 = sound.apply_stereo_gain(-6.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: @FedericoLeoni you can install from github directly with `pip install git+https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub.git@master`

Comment: Mmmmm. Exactly where do I ned to put the pan/gain info?
    
    sound = AudioSegment.from_ogg('/home/effe/voice_orders/sound1.ogg')
    sound.set_gain(-5.0,0.0) # or sound.pan(-1.0)
    play(sound)

Doesn't change the volume channel..

Comment: @FedericoLeoni (1) I've renamed the methods and published a release on pypi (so you can instal with pip) | Answer updated to reflect changes. `AudioSegment` objects are immutable so you have to assign the result: `panned_sound = sound.pan(…)` and then work on the result

Comment: Yes, I did realize it after some trials... panned = sound.pan(+1.0)
    play(panned) do the job. Thanks!